# Validate TextEdit in Tasker

Tags: android, textedit, tasker

How to validate a textedit field in a tasker scene.

**Requirement**: I have a textedit field and a submit button in a tasker scene.
Once the submit button is clicked i need to validate and see if the textedit field is empty or not.

**What i tried**:

1. Create a variable and update it everytime textedit is modified.
2. On submit, check the variable if it is null.(using matches null)
3. The above didnt work.

Can someone tell me how i can validate the textedit field.
ex: if %Textedit_variable ~ null

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this

1. When button is clicked fetch the text from your `textedit` into a string.
2. Try something like this:

   `String s= mytextedit.getText().toString();`
3. See if the string is empty by using something like this:

`if(s.equals("")){
 //the user hasn't entered anything
  }`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain how to implement the above in Tasker.

Comment: You just need to put the above code into the onClick() for your button.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/bxP5UjEKH4I

I figured it out from the replies on the above discussion.

- I used testElement to store the current value of the textEdit field to %TextEdit_Var
- On button click, i use the below condition in the tap action for the button:

`If %TextEdit_Var ~ *TextEdit_Var`